# ReadyState property in QTP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, qtp

Could you please explain difference between ReadyState property used in QTP and JavaSript document.readyState?

Comment: Where is `ReadyState` used in QTP? I am not familiar with this property.

Comment: you can use it as `browser(...).getRoProperty("readyState")` or `browser(...).Object.readyState` to see if the browser is ready with loading and processing data. If it becomes 4 or "complete", the browser is ready.

Comment: Is browser(...).Object.readyState the same as javascript document.readystate?

Answer (score 1):

Both basically does the same. Just the application changes, Using ReadyState in property, you can sync with the page loading and wait until webpage is completely loaded.

In Javascript, you can do much more than that. For example you might have seen that GMAIL displayes the plain text format of the mini inbox while loading. So, you can use ReadyState to some alternative actions in javascript like displaying a message like Loading, Please Wait, or show some progress bar kind of stuff.

Comment: So in both cases we are waiting of full loading of DOM tree. I mean browser().Object.readyState == 4 in QTP and JS document.readyState == "complete". So these verifications are the same. Am I correct?

Comment: In a way yes. in case of QTP, we mostly use it for waiting for full loading. In case of Javascript we use that time to do something else or hold the process.